# Test Account for Android Emulator

Tags: android, testing, google-account

I've an Android application with Google login, to test this application and do login, in a Virtual Device Emulator, i've added a personal account in that Emulator.

Question is: Can i add a test account instead of my personal? (but i have to create that, and in creation process Google ask me my personal phone number...)

Do you usually create another account or you use your personal?

Comment: You can do either or. There is nothing wrong with using your personal one.

Comment: @Doomsknight thanks for answer, but i would like to separate if this is possible. I think that in team in real work they don't use personal account, maybe they create another to test, but i don't know

Comment: At work I would use my person one on my machine if it is easier. But if its going to be shared i would set up another one.

Comment: @Doomsknight thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your personal account, thats ok, all the developers i know and me always use this way.
Or do you have some problem with this?

Comment: I don't have any problem with that but a test account separated from real/personal one i think it's better (team work, initial security issue). Google doesn't provide a test account? Like a one-way account...but if it doesn't provide like i've searched, nothing matters. I'll use a fake personal account dedicated to test. Thanks to all for answer

Comment: I received one of those fun "Google Maps Timeline" emails saying I traveled to the Googleplex, after using my personal account on an emulator. Who knows what else is happening under the hood.